# Instant Notifications

Tags: php, codeigniter, caching, browser-cache

What I'm wanting to know and look into is find out how I can have a page/function or what not load every couple of seconds or what not that way i can report a notification instantly to my user in my CodeIgniter CMS that they have a new personal message in their inbox.

When the user gets to the dashboard from the login screen when the user clicks on the envelop it will display the last 5 messages and if they recieve a syncronous pm message it will immediately notify them with a little overlay that will show and it will increment the red circle if it already exists or add it as 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your javascript is already loaded, I assume your also using jquery. So with that.

My Suggestion would be a bit similar to Chad's. But more reusable in a sense, should you want to call it independently for whatever reason.

```
var $messageCountJSON;
var messageTimer = '';
var messageInterval = 5;

//assumed JSON response is {"count":"20"} for example sake.

function messageCount(displayElementID)
{
    $.get('/url/to/script/', function(data)
    {
        $messageCountJSON = data; 
    }, 'json');
    if(displayElementID != null && displayElementID != undefined && displayElementID != '')
    {
        $('#'+displayElementID).html(data.count);
    }
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
    messageTimer = setInterval(function(){messageCount();}, messageInterval*1000);
});

//you can optionally kill the timed interval with something like
$('#element').click(function(){clearInterval(messageTimer);})
```

I am of course just pulling this out of my arse on a whim here as I type so its not 100% tested, but worth a shot none the less.

Worth Honorable Mention, this isn't instant notification. This is Asynchronous; notification, meaning every 5 seconds in this case you will send a get request to a script and get data back from it accordingly. If you want instantaneous notification you can look into Synchronous; data transmitted between the script point and client side never closes . Both have there pluses and draw backs. Asynchronous is more commonly used as its the lesser of the 2 evils. More so as Synchronous without the right hardware to back it and the without the right setup, can just cause your site to lock up and freeze the users browser.

Comment: Someone should change $this->load->library('javascript') to $this->load->('jquery'), because that's actually what you're doing there. Your way is a little more thorough. I hate to encourage people to do either, however, because on Android browsers this is the script that makes me never want to visit the site again (the page acts like a broken record).

Answer (score 2):

In your controller:

```
$this->load->library('javascript');
```

In your view:

```
<script>
$(window).load(function checkMessages() {
$.ajax({
url: 'instant_messenger.php', 
success: function(data) {
$('messagebox').html(data);
}});
setTimeout('checkMessages', 5000);
});
</script>
```

...where 'instant_messenger.php' is your script that checks for new messages and 'messagebox' is the html element where you want the message to display.

It is a basic example, but this script will run check_messages.php every 5 seconds and put the output on the user's page without them having to reload.